# How to let user edit URL that my custom button in context menu redirects to?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I've done my fist chrome extension - a context menu button that opens highlighted text in the link.

What I want to do next, is to let the user of the extension edit the url that the highlighted text will be used at the end of.

Think of it as right-click highlighted and context menu button "Search 'highlighted' in Google however, I want the user to let manually type the url.

How to set up simple extension Options page and redirect input URL to script.js code?

So far I've only been able to create a manifest.json and script.js where I typed the URL myself, whereas the goal is to let the user type the URL.

What I have so far:

```
chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + info.selectionText
  });
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Search: %s", 
  contexts:["selection"], 
  onclick: getword
```

Say user wants a quick access to highlighted text in wikipedia.

1. Sets up "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" on the extension settings.
2. Highlights "Ontario".
3. Right clicks and chooses the extension button.
4. Chrome opens a new tab "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontario".

Comment: You should be able to use the native [storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) to save the preferences on the options page and read from it on your context menu action.

Comment: An extension's options page is displayed in a separate tab, which is quite a disruptive UX. A much better approach is to show the dialog right inside the page, which you can do in a content script using the standard DOM stuff after your background script sends a message to the tab via chrome.tabs.sendMessage.